# Vuex watch not triggereing on all state changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to watch for vuex state changes in a vue component. (I am extending a larger project and would like to react to table rows being clicked in one component by taking some of the row information and render an image based on this.)

The state change works (I can see it in the vue developer tools), but the watch is only triggered once on initial load/hot reload. I am new to vue and vuex (and pug and ts) so I guess I am missing something basic.

I found a lot of answers here stating that one should just watch the store, obviously there is more to it. I tried several variations (directly accessing the store, importing the store module and using a computed property, none of which is working, see code below. What do I need to do to make any of the watches working?

When I click the test button I created, all information is present, too.

```
<template lang="pug">
    div
        p current image {{ imageUrl }}
        el-button(plain @click="onMyButtonClick") Button
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Getter, Action, Mutation, State } from 'vuex-class';
import { RecordModuleState } from '../store/modules/records/types';

@Component
export default class ImageViewer extends Vue {
    @State('records') private records!: RecordModuleState;

    onMyButtonClick (): void {
        console.log('Button clicked:', this.records.currentRow)
    }

    get imageUrl() {
        return this.records.currentRow // also tried this.$store.state.records.currentRow
    }

    @Watch('this.$store.state.records', { immediate:true, deep: true })
    onCurrentRowChanged(val: string, oldVal: string) {
        console.log('watch1', val)
    }

    @Watch('records', { immediate:true, deep: true })
    onCurrentRowChanged2(val: string, oldVal: string) {
        console.log('watch2', val)
    }

    @Watch('imageUrl', { immediate:true, deep: true })
    onCurrentRowChanged3(val: string, oldVal: string) {
        console.log('watch3', val)
    }

}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@State('records') private records!: RecordModuleState;`
 you should be using `@Getter records`.

Comment: many thanks for taking a look and for your suggestion. Could you elaborate a bit, please? Is using the state wrong overall and are getters giving functionality that would solve my problem that the state does not have? I.e. why would one work and the other fail? Btw, just swapping the two lines did not work, I think the code is not defining a getter for records, I am investigating this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me the right way. After implementing the missing getters and reviewing mutations, I got it to work now either way, i.e. watching for a change in the computed property or via watching with the getter. Thanks for pointing me the right way! (Still interested to know why I should use the getter over accessing the store and if there are any pros/cons). Thanks!